# Font Size Viewport but with a MIN size or mapped to the container instead

Tags: css, parent, font-size, viewport-units

Some code adjusts the font size based on the viewport. As much as this is what I am after the body has a min-width. Once this min-width is crossed how would viewport scaling of the text be stopped.

Either some king of min-font-size is needed or the font size needs to be mapped to the size of the parent element. Can this be done without JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query in your css to set a fixed font size when the viewport goes under a certain width:

```
BODY {min-width: 500px;}
P {font-size: 2vw;}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    P {font-size: 10px;}
}
```